# NS-2.34 DYMO patch

Tags: routes, patch, ns2, dymo

i'm trying to add DYMO routing protocol to NS-2.34 but it didn't work, 
i'm following this tuto : https://khaledben.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/patching-dymo-um-in-ns-2/

in other hand i can not find dymo-3.patch for ns-2.34 (http://masimum.inf.um.es/?Software:DYMOUM is no more available).

could any one help me to get the patch file or fix this issue please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dymoum-0.3.tgz" is here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeTFjUkc4T3NGWjA/view?usp=sharing

ns-allinone-2.34 is old. `gcc / g++` version 3.4.6 or 4.1.2 can be used.

I did :

```
cd ns-allinone-2.34/
patch -p0 < Edited-dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch
export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./install
```

Testing`dymoum/ns/test/{test_2n_m.tcl, test_2n.tcl, test_3n_m.tcl, test_3n.tcl}` : All OK. And four nice `nam` animations.

---

Second run with Dymoum and ns-2.34 : I made up a new patch from { `ns234_gcc49.patch` + `Edited-dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch` + the `dymoum/` folder} to `DYMO-03-all_ns234-gcc5.patch`. So with a stock ns-allinone-2.34 it is :

```
cd ns-allinone-2.34/
patch -p0 < DYMO-03-all_ns234-gcc5.patch
./install
```

Link, `DYMO-03-all_ns234-gcc5.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbHNsUzQ3QXdMa0E/view?usp=sharing

---

---

Also available : DYMO-03-all__**ns235**.patch
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNejVmQ0duZmRHUEU/view?usp=sharing

For ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz ( All gcc versions 4.6 - 5.2 ) 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

---

Other links 1) The old `dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch` (Don't use it) 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNLXJzdURCZmRzWjA/view?usp=sharing ... uploaded as "old" : `dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.old.patch`

2) "dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch", edited : `Edited-dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch` 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeS1oVlkzd0hsd2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Patches must be present to be applied : Make a copy of the patch to ns-allinone.2.3x/ . **Your OS** : Please edit your above posting to include OS specs, i.e. name, version, architecture..

Comment: could you please give me a link to download "dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch" ?

Comment: `dymoum_ns-2.34_v0.3.patch` was added to my post.

Comment: "blackholeDYMO" : That's a new topic. Please start a new thread about blackholeDYMO .

Comment: Knud Larsen , could you help me please to find out the function that is responsible for acception of the RREP if the node is the destination , i found all functions that sends/receives a RREP/RREQ but not the function or a code that check if the RREP is for that specific node that sent a RREQ (the response for its RREQ). (DYMOU protocol that you have sent to me its patch)

Comment: »» RREQ (the response for its RREQ) «« : Sorry, is beyond my knowledge.  Please try asking Google for ´´ns2 RREQ´´ .