# Can't run dymoum test_2n.tcl file on ns-2.35 in ubuntu14.04

Tags: tcl, ns2

After successfully applied `/home/uday/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/DYMO-03-all__ns235.patch`

When i tried to run the following `dymoum/ns/test/test_2n.tcl` code it gives error and i can't solve that error .I tried my best but i failed ...Kindly anyone look at the code and help me to solve error.The test code is given below:

```
# ======================================================================
# Define options
# ======================================================================
set opt(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel  ;# channel type
set opt(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround ;# radio-propagation model
set opt(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy          ;# network interface type
set opt(mac)            Mac/802_11               ;# MAC type
set opt(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue  ;# interface queue type
set opt(ll)             LL                       ;# link layer type
set opt(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna      ;# antenna model
set opt(ifqlen)         50                       ;# max packet in ifq
set opt(nn)             2                        ;# number of mobilenodes
set opt(adhocRouting)   DYMOUM                   ;# routing protocol

set opt(cp)             ""                       ;# connection pattern file
set opt(sc)             ""                       ;# node movement file. 

set opt(x)              400                      ;# x coordinate of topology
set opt(y)              600                      ;# y coordinate of topology
set opt(seed)           0.0                      ;# seed for random number gen.
set opt(stop)           40                       ;# time to stop simulation

set opt(cbr-start)      10.0
# ============================================================================

#
# check for random seed
#
if {$opt(seed) > 0} {
    puts "Seeding Random number generator with $opt(seed)\n"
    ns-random $opt(seed)
}

#
# create simulator instance
#
set ns_ [new Simulator]

#
# control DYMOUM behaviour from this script
#
Agent/DYMOUM set debug_ true
Agent/DYMOUM set no_path_acc_ true
Agent/DYMOUM set reissue_rreq_ false
Agent/DYMOUM set s_bit_ true
Agent/DYMOUM set hello_ival_ 1

#
# open traces
#
set tracefd  [open test_2n.tr w]
set namtrace [open test_2n.nam w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $opt(x) $opt(y)

#
# create topography object
#
set topo [new Topography]

#
# define topology
#
$topo load_flatgrid $opt(x) $opt(y)

#
# create God
#
create-god $opt(nn)

#
# configure mobile nodes
#
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $opt(adhocRouting) \
                 -llType $opt(ll) \
                 -macType $opt(mac) \
                 -ifqType $opt(ifq) \
                 -ifqLen $opt(ifqlen) \
                 -antType $opt(ant) \
                 -propType $opt(prop) \
                 -phyType $opt(netif) \
                 -channelType $opt(chan) \
                 -topoInstance $topo \
                 -wiredRouting OFF \
                 -agentTrace ON \
                 -routerTrace ON \
                 -macTrace OFF

for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn)} {incr i} {
    set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
}

#
# positions
#
$node_(0) set X_ 200.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 200.0
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(1) set X_ 300.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 200.0
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.0

#
# setup UDP connection
#
set udp [new Agent/UDP]
set null [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(0) $udp
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null
$ns_ connect $udp $null
set cbr [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr set packetSize_ 512
$cbr set rate_ 20Kb
$cbr attach-agent $udp
$ns_ at $opt(cbr-start) "$cbr start"

#
# print (in the trace file) routing table and other
# internal data structures on a per-node basis
# TODO: implement this
#$ns_ at 15.0 "[$node_(0) agent 255] print_rtable"

#
# source connection-pattern and node-movement scripts
#
if { $opt(cp) == "" } {
    puts "*** NOTE: no connection pattern specified."
    set opt(cp) "none"
} else {
    puts "Loading connection pattern..."
    source $opt(cp)
}
if { $opt(sc) == "" } {
    puts "*** NOTE: no scenario file specified."
    set opt(sc) "none"
} else {
    puts "Loading scenario file..."
    source $opt(sc)
    puts "Load complete..."
}

#
# define initial node position in nam
#
for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn)} {incr i} {
    $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 20
}     

#
# tell all nodes when the simulation ends
#
for {set i 0} {$i < $opt(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at $opt(stop).0 "$node_($i) reset";
}

$ns_ at $opt(stop).0002 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"
$ns_ at $opt(stop).0001 "stop"

proc stop {} {
    global ns_ tracefd namtrace
    $ns_ flush-trace
    close $tracefd
    close $namtrace
}

#
# begin simulation
#
puts "Starting Simulation..."

$ns_ run
```

It shows error:
      root@uday-HP-15-Notebook-PC:/home/uday/Downloads/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/dymoum/ns/test# ns test_2n.tcl

```
invalid command name "Agent/DYMOUM"
    while executing
    "Agent/DYMOUM set debug_ true"
    (file "test_2n.tcl" line 42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. stackoverflow → [NS-2.34 DYMO patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146962/ns-2-34-dymo-patch/43150616#43150616)

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < DYMO-03-all__ns235.patch
./install
cd ns-2.35/
cp ns ns235-dymo
sudo cp ns235-dymo /usr/local/bin/

------------ Simulation ------------
ns235-dymo test_2n.tcl
 num_nodes is set 2
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
*** NOTE: no connection pattern specified.
*** NOTE: no scenario file specified.
Starting Simulation...
DYMOUM agent started in node 0
        no_path_acc=1
        reissue_rreq=0
        s_bit=1
        hello_ival=1

node 0: hello_send: sending HELLO
DYMOUM agent started in node 1
        no_path_acc=1
        reissue_rreq=0
        s_bit=1
        hello_ival=1

node 1: hello_send: sending HELLO
.
.
node 0: process_data: route to dst 1 updated
node 1: tap: route to src 0 updated
NS EXITING...
```

*Your errors* : Seems you are using a wrong copy of **ns** i.e. an 'ns' with no Dymoum ... or you have a failed build. The safe way : Use an executable "ns-name" which is present in a system PATH = /usr/local/bin/.

Dymoum simulation examples : Dymoum-examples.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

---

Ref. comment **1.** : OK with Ubuntu 14.04-amd64 installed to hard-disk. Same file sizes for test_2n.nam (89.5kB), test_2n.tr (64kB), and same 486 lines of text output : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5v84a9ubnip3m1h/Dymo-test_2n.tcl.txt?dl=0

---

Ref. comment **2 - 3.** : New patch `Dymo-blackhole-idsAODV_ns235.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S63-743G9Et86yXWhaYkpSR_3wOAsUHG/view?usp=sharing

The new executable `ns235_Dymo-blackhole-idsAODV` was tested OK with Dymoum simulations, blackholeaodv2005~2013-examples-05.17.tar.gz, idsAODV-examples-05.17.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: after applying the above commands  it successfully shows ns is existing but it gives the output as  unknown msg is received                                                                      node 1: hello_send: sending HELLO
node 0: generic_process_message: unknown msg type 9 received in nsif from 1
node 0: uerr_send: sending UERR to 24
node 0: uerr_send: could not send a UERR to 24 because there is no suitable route                                                                                   
How to solve this error?  How to remove wrong patch file in ns-2.35?

Comment: sir, How to implement balckhole attack using Dymoum in ns2.35?

Comment: Is it possible to apply IDS for Dymoum in ns-2.35?

Comment: **Add 1.** Errors: Could be caused by Ubuntu. I will test. You can have as many ns-allinone-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time. But, do never add any *PATH text to .bashrc . Not required. Just keep all "ns-name" in /usr/local/bin/. So just setup another "ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz" in a new directory.  **Add 2.** Blackhole : I will test if possible. (Don't see why not.) **Add 3.** `aodvIDS` : Probably.  I'll test, and let you know.

Comment: how to remove outdated patch file from ns-2.35?

Comment: I would never save a wrecked ns2. And have never done. Delete, and start from scratch. But actually the reverse patch command could work : `patch -p1 -R < path/file.patch`  https://www.drupal.org/patch/reverse ← ← https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=patch+reverse

Comment: sir, How to implement balckhole attack using OLSR and IDSOLSR in ns2.35?

Comment: Blackhole attack : I never saw any attack modules specifically for OLSR, be it blackhole or anything else. (May be wormhole?) ... ... `idsAODV` is aodv. Did you find an IDS for olsr ?

Comment: For black hole on OLSR can be done by making MPR node as blackhole node but I don't have any idea how to do it?  No I haven't found anything for IDSOLSR. Is there any reason that we cannot implememt Ids for OLSR ?