# NS2-Modification of protocol - dymo

Tags: ns2

i need to add dymo protocole in NS2.35 ubunto 16.04 and find tcl && awk files if there enyone work of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ns-2.35 + Dymoum

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz   // 2014..2017 update: gcc -4.4..-5 (<= 5.4)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < DYMO-03-all__ns235.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNejVmQ0duZmRHUEU/view?usp=sharing

```
./install
cd ns-2.35/
cp ns ns-dymo
sudo cp ns-dymo /usr/local/bin/
sudo make install
cd ../nam-1.15/
sudo make install
```

----------- Simulation ------------

**ns-dymo** dymo-is.tcl .... etc. examples from 'Dymoum-examples.tar.gz' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbnk1M0NDQmFjSk0/view?usp=sharing

DYMO links [NS-2.34 DYMO patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146962/ns-2-34-dymo-patch/43150616#43150616) ... and https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=ns2%20dymo ... **and** https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dymoum

`awk, perl` scripts ns2 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing

Plot graphs **1**. http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html ... **1a**. 
https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

---

The ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing

~3000 ns2 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

---

EDIT : You can also use the application `dymo-ns_2.35-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb` (2.5MB)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0xuZSVmbKXLbyplX0_9NIhB1HYeR51l/view?usp=sharing → Provides `/usr/local/{bin/ns235-dymo, lib/dymo/{lib/*tcl*, bin/tclsh*}}`

Download, and install: `sudo gdebi Downloads/dymo-ns_2.35-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb`

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you by clicking on the gray tick ;)

Comment: i added dymo correctly but when i try to execute filedymo.tcl with command ns-dymo dymo-is.tcl
 affiched these error invalid command name "Agent/DYMOUM"
    while executing
"Agent/DYMOUM set debug_ true"
    (file "dymo-is.tcl" line 22) and with these command ns-dymo dymo-is.tcl  affiche these error ns-dymo dymo-is.tcl where is the problem i need it for my research please ? thank you

Comment: Is your Ubuntu 16.04 installed to hard disk ? ... I edited the answer: Added `dymo-ns_2.35-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb` : To be used, if you have problems creating a good executable "ns".

Comment: yes u use ubuntu 16.04 thank you i work for QoS of protocols Dymo and Aodv

Comment: **Repeat** : Is your Ubuntu 16.04 installed to hard disk ? Or something else ? Like inside Windows©, or a virtual machine. ... I.e. VirtualBox and WMware have produced very poor ns2 executable´s the last six months.